# Encountered problem while integrating devstack - osm (open source mano)

Tags: integration, openstack, devstack

I'm currently trying to develop a cloud in my pc using virtual box. The idea is that I have 2 virtual machines, one which devstack installed (all in one) and the other with osm mano. Right now both have everything installed. Hence, I can log in to mano via user and password 'admin' as well as to devstack.

Current properties:

VM1 (devstack): IP (enp0s8) -> 192.168.56.101
Login to 192.168.56.101 -> correct

VM2 (mano):     IP (enp0s8) -> 192.168.56.105
Login to 192.168.56.105 -> correct

As some of you may guess, I have 2 network interfaces in every vm, the first one being NAT (enp0s3 with 10.0.2.15 IP) and the second one being Host Only (192.168.56.x according to virtual box).

Needless to say, I can ping from one virtual machine to another without any problem.

Now, in the past I've being using devstack (ubuntu 18.04) in order to play with it a little bit, learn how to deploy instances, create groups and so on. Indeed, I developed a topology with an instance as a router and nagios as the monitoring tool system. It worked and I learnt a lot!

Anyway, what I want in this case is starting from scratch (scratch meaning having downloaded mano and devstack but without going further). So here I am, trying to integrate OSM with Devstack, making use of osm-vim command as it is:

osm vim-create --name openstack-site --user admin --password my_openstack_password --auth_url http://192.168.56.101:5000/v3 --tenant admin --account_type openstack

In this case, my openrc file (downloaded from horizon) resulted in my auth_url being:
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://192.168.56.101:5000/v3

What I'm trying to get my head into is how it's possible that this doesn't work, as whenever I log-in to mano web interface (after osm-vim command) I go to VIM accounts and operational state equals to "error".

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, as I've being struggling for a week now.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. At the beginning I thought It was a network problem, but finally I found out It was due to a SSL problem. The most easy solution is to put a specific flag to avoid the SSL verification until the developers fix it. "--config '{insecure: True}'"

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when I finished installing OSM-10 and OpenStack-Ussuri for Ubuntu18.04 some days ago. I solved this problem by change the url "--auth_url http//:192.168.23.18:5000/v3" to "-- auth_url http//:controller:5000/v3" and put "192.168.23.18 controller" in the ro container "/etc/hosts". The "controller" here is the host name where you install your openstack and which is used is your keystone authentication urls. Maybe you also have solved this problem but this problem is so troublesome and I hope more people do not be annoyed at this~